# Url AS A STRING sent from backend to frontend, been changed automatically from http to https, anyone know why?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

Could anyone help me with this please, I couldn't figure out why.

Web application is using HTTPS protocol, SpringMVC as mvc framework, Spring Security for security.

In controller I set a string into a modelMap, which is gonna used by SpringMVC to render the frontend page.
like:

```
model.addAttribute("actionUrl", http://localhost:8080/web/dothings);
```

this attribute will be set as ACTION of a FORM

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="${actionUrl}">
```

But, when I inspect the source code of the JSP page, the action has been changed to

```
https://localhost:8080/web/dothings
```

Like:

```
<form id="test" action="https://localhost:8080/web/dothings">
```

is it changes by libraries or servlet container?

Answer (score 0):

You can send only URL not with full context path.From your controller send only url path

```
model.addAttribute("actionUrl", "/dothings");
```

And in your jsp page

```
<form id="test" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}${actionUrl}">
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: `contextPath` only prints your web context. not your protocol. For your web application is prints `/web`. let application decide which is your protocol and dn.

Comment: Also it's a standard way, not to put direct ip or  `localhost` in your web-apps controller. @Asikar

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my local, but I didn't see your problem. I think it's something about your configurations.

Instead of examining the configurations, you can use this approach with urls:

Now you are using this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/dothings
```

Change this into this and give it a try:

```
//localhost:8080/web/dothings
```

This is a protocol relative url.
Using `//` at the beggining of the url, leaves the scheme part to the browser. Browser choses between `http` and `https` depending on the page url's own scheme.